# Question on bound/unbound forms in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a form populated with data from two tables, say table A and table B. The data from table A refers to a single row in A but the data that I have to retrieve from B is several rows long. I succeeded in doing so by setting up an unbound form and running a SQL JOIN query to fetch the appropriate data in VBA.

Then with VBA I was able to distinguish the data from the multiple rows in B.

Is it possible to achieve the same with a bound form so that I save myself from excessive coding? I can't figure out a way to populate my controls in the form with data from the rows in B.

Comment: Why can't you bind controls with table B fields? Normally a form is used for data entry/edit to one table. Why have both tables in RecordSource? Why not use form/subform?

Comment: What do I have to do to close this qustion? I think it has been answered.

Comment: SO operates differently from other forums. Closing a question means it is considered not appropriate for SO and closing is done by member votes. Once closed answers cannot be offered unless enough members vote to reopen question. Your question has an answer that you have accepted therefore it is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your two tables are related, that is, you search in B based on a value on A. If that's the case, the usual solution in access is to use a main form and a subform inside the main form. Then you link the two. When you insert the subform, a wizard will appear asking for the relation. You set up the columns that are common in the two tables, and everything works, usually. You can anyway add the relation later.